# mount: /media/mountName: operation permitted for root only

Tags: pi-4, debian, mount, root

I tried to mount window shared folder on raspberry pi but it is not successful yet. Every time I run the command to mount, it just keeps showing `mount error:Host is down.`

Here is what I have tried to achieve mount shared folder on Pi

First, I get the window shared folder. In my case, it is

```
\\100.179.180.90\MyShare\TempFolder
Username =<USER>
Password =<Pass>
```

Then, I start to use this command in pi.

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=<USER> //100.179.180.90/MyShare/TempFolder /media/mountName
```

However, I have got this error.

```
mount error(112): Host is down
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Then I edit .smbcredentials using sudo nano ~/.smbcredentials

```
username=<USER>
password=<Pass>
```

and fstab using `sudo nano /etc/fstab`.

```
//100.179.180.90/MyShare/TempFolder /media/mountName cifs credentials=/home/pi/.smbcredentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,vers=3.0,nounix 0 0
```

Then I put `sudo mount -a` then the error is still the same.

```
Host is down.
```

But then when I check FileManager,

```
mount: /media/mountName: operation permitted for root only.
```

Even though I use `/mnt/test` it keeps showing me error of `host is down.`

I have used different versions of SMB protocols stated in pi documentation. For example,

```
sudo mount.cifs //100.179.180.90/MyShare/TempFolder /mnt/test -o user=<USER>,vers=3
Password for CIM_ADMIN@//100.179.180.90/MyuShare/TempFolder:
```

I thought it is root access issue but I am not sure.
I can ping the ipaddress(100.179.180.90) from (`\\100.179.180.90\MyShare\TempFolder`)) from pi and it works.
But mounting window shared folder is giving me headache.

Comment: How did you mount? What are you mounting?

Comment: I am mounting a window shared folder on raspberry pi. I followed this article(https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341844/how-do-i-permanently-mount-a-windows-network-share-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? if so specify in tags. When I asked how i meant WHAT YOU DID - not a link (especially a very poor post like this). There are LOTS of Questions on this site about mounting a Samba share.

Comment: DO NOT try to mount in `/media` which is used for automount use normal `/mnt` (or a dedicated directory.

Comment: Ok thanks so I am using Debian. And I put in sudo mount -t cifs -o username=User //100.180.130.25/TempShare/MyFolder  /media/mountName. This is what I did and found that the error is host is down. So I check in file manager and I saw that it is for root only. I will update the question again as I think I need to write what I did to get the shared drive and got errors.

Answer (score 0):

For example I use `sudo mount.cifs //Milliways.local/Images /mnt/Image -o user=ian` to mount a share on my Pi (for user ian).

I can't comment on Windows. See [Samba (SMB/CIFS)](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/remote-access.html#samba-smbcifs)

Comment: Thank you. Just a quick check. User should be the window username right?

Comment: I have used different versions of SMB protocols stated in pi documentation but the error still persists.

Comment: @MyatKaung User can be the username of any account that has access to your share. Linux usernames are case sensitive. You may (depending on your config) have to set an account password to authenticate, or change network profile/security policy to allow access with a blank password.